# Can someone provide the logic for "selecting all the birthdays that occured within the last 90 days"?

Tags: excel-formula, powerbi, dashboard

edited*

I'm currently using Microsoft Power BI

**Can someone provide the logic for "selecting all the birthdays that occured within the last 90 days relative to today's date"?**

For example:

*I have a table called "ClientTable" with the birthdays of 100 clients in an MM/DD/YYYY format. Today's date is 09/15/2022. I now want to list out all the of the clients that had a birthday within the last 90 days. So essentially, I am looking for a list of all the clients that had a birthday between 06/15/2022 and 09/15/2022.*

This is how I attempted to solve it:

I first parsed out the Month and Day components of the BirthDate field into two separate columns. I then created a new table called "MasterDay" with all the dates in a single year and also parsed out the Month and Date components into separate columns:

MasterDate

| Date | Month | Day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DD/MM/YYYY | MM | DD |
| DD/MM/YYYY | MM | DD |

ClientTable

| BirthDate | Month | Day | ClientID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DD/MM/YYYY | MM | DD | 85 |
| DD/MM/YYYY | MM | DD | 7 |

I then created a relationship between the two tables "ClientTable" and "MasterDay" on their respective month and day columns. So that when placing the complete "Date" column from the MasterDay table into a slicer it would select all the corresponding rows from the "BirthDate" column in ClientDate table.

The issue I'm having is that when slicing for a range that begins in the middle of a particular month, say between 06/15/2022 and 09/15/2022, it picks up **all** of the birthdates in the months of June and September like 06/07/2022 or 09/23/2022 despite it not being included in the slicing range.

Thanks, G

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free coding service. Could you please share with us the effort you took to solve the question yourself or are you just looking for someone else to do your job? And if you're new to PowerBI: Here are your first steps: [Power BI Basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/fundamentals/desktop-getting-started)

Comment: Power BI doesn’t support two comumn relationships.  The relationships should be on the BirthDate column.

Comment: Setting the relationship to the birthdate column alone only yields birthdates for clients born in the the year 2022. If I had a client born in the year 1850, it is not included.

Comment: Then combine day and month into a single column and filter on that.

Comment: Do a datediff calculated column on today() and today -90, use that on the birthdate or day column to flag which days are in the last 90 days. Use that flag to drive the selection

Answer (score 1):

In Power BI you would simply use a [Relative Date Slicer or Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/desktop-slicer-filter-date-range).

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of this slicer and am actually using it, but it doesn't solve my issue. I added more clarity to the question to give more insight.